# Get stats according criteria (e.i: _id) on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering how I can stand a query to get stats according criteria, see below the context

I have 8 collections within my DB, I would like to get stats from these collections according 2 criteria.

To match the collection called **Tenants**, I would like to match **_id**, for the others, the property **tenantId**.

I tried this command following doc informations

```
> db.collections.stats({indexDetails: true, indexDetailsKey: {_id: ObjectId("60804fd2fdae12046ba82a85"), tenantId: ObjectId("60804fd2fdae12046ba82a85")}})
```

result

```
{
    "ns" : "koopt.collections",
    "size" : 0,
    "count" : 0,
    "storageSize" : 0,
    "totalSize" : 0,
    "nindexes" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 0,
    "indexDetails" : {
        
    },
    "indexSizes" : {
        
    },
    "scaleFactor" : 1,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Thanks in advance for your inputs :)

Comment: [db.collection.stats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/#db.collection.stats--) returns metadata about the collection, and doesn't support querying the documents.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: within the DB I have the data for plenty of different "session" for exemple in the collection people,  I have 10 people for session #1 and 28 people for session #2. So I would like to know how much space take 10 people from the session #1 out of global available space. I hope its clear enough

Answer (score 1):

The stats information is not calculated on demand.  MongoDB tracks the data and stores it separately.  The `db.collection.stats()` function retrieves that metadata to return.  Since it doesn't look at any documents, it is not able to filter by document.

It does provide and average object size, so you can get an estimate of how much data is stored in 10 documents by multiplying the average by 10.

Each page of the data file is compressed individually, and compression rates vary, so you could calculate the average compression ratio from the size and storageSize, and use that to calculate an approximate storage size for the 10 documents.

The alternative is to query the documents, iterate the list in the client, and check the size of each.

In the mongo shell you could use the `Object.bsonsize` helper to get the size of a document.

Comment: Thanks for these details. I'm gonna follow your advice, in order to get the an estimation by performing the average of each collection.